# Inverse Torsion Radical of a Tilting Theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

I wonder if it is possible to say that the existence of a certain module exist.
Let $A$ be a finite dimensional, hereditary, wild, connected algebra. 
Let $(\mathcal{T}, \mathcal{F})$ be a torsion theory in $A$. Let $M\in \mathcal{T}$. We know we can define for all modules $M$ the torsion radical $tM$ which is the sum of all images of homomorphism from $\mathcal{T}$ to $M$. It is also the biggest submodule of $M$ which is a torsion module, by definition. I wonder if for a given $M$, we can say that there exists a module $N$ such that $t(\tau_AN)=M$.

We can reformulate the question as is the functor $t\circ\tau_A: \mathcal{T} \rightarrow \mathcal{T}$ surjective on modules?

Greetings
Bunlong

Comment: Hi: Let me say that your post is fine, but the one thing I would advise is to please refrain from salutations in questions or answers. It's just clutter.

Comment: Which functor is $\tau_A$?